# Find and replace the string wp_* in a template

Tags: php, string

This is my original string:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <h2>wp_title</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="wp_img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              wp_contentFirst                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              wp_contentSecond
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
```

How do I go over all the **wp_** (including the underscore) ? IN **PHP**.

My idea is to stop once I reach "wp_" and take all characters from this point until I reach anything that is not A-z and 0-9

I've tried strstr function but I couldn't get it done.

I hope I was clear enough. If not, please let me know and I'll explain myself better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? can you please give some more example.

Comment: Yes, look at my code, you can notice wp_ repeating but having a different name everytime. I want to take that name, or actually all the names within an array.

Comment: Indeed a horrible title. My english is yet to be perfect but I'm trying my best! Thank you Wesley Murch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will get all wp_* strings from given string:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOD
<div class="container-fluid">
        <h2>wp_title</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="wp_img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              wp_contentFirst                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              wp_contentSecond
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
EOD;

if (preg_match_all('/wp_[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $str, $m)) {
    $allWpStrings = $m[0];
    print_r($allWpStrings);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, you're awesome! Thank you. I'm sorry I can't upvote you. I flagged as the answer though. Thanks again.